# Faster linkable ring signatures libraries

Tags: signature, implementation

I need a fast linkable ring signatures library, something that is O(log(n)) and n is the ring size.
I read a few papers about these kinds of schemes but I didnt find any implementations of them.
Here are few of the papers I read:
https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0304397512009528?token=6FCBA7389B1AF78F2C3B52B706F5C9E13130E044B14FD7F6DD55632C02F6B742E9CE2B288610AC2FFE0FCF198729F510&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20221009102248

https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/196.pdf

https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/281.pdf

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Compact-linkable-ring-signatures-and-applications-Goodell-Noether/2899b52fecbe3881997cbaab518657ffdbffb287

If anyone knows about any implementations of this papers it would help me a lot, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Last cited paper (https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Compact-linkable-ring-signatures-and-applications-Goodell-Noether/2899b52fecbe3881997cbaab518657ffdbffb287)'s first authors were at that time part of MRL (Monero Research Lab): and CLSAG is still the ring signature used today (for a quick recap of the various flavours: https://www.getmonero.org/library/RingsCheatsheet20210301.pdf).. so I guess you could check Monero's source code, which is open source, for the implementation.. I would suggest https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto.h and crypto.cpp for, at least, library first-inspiration

Comment: I am trying yhis right now, but I cant seem to figure out how to extract the code from monero, I get a lot of errors and I cant figure out what to do, I am starting to give up, Do you have any idea about how can I extract the ring signatures code?

Comment: not personally, cause I'm not a Monero coder so I don't know where to start from (the Monero codebase isn't a simple one imho) ... but maybe you can try asking for help to their "Development Workgroup", they are kind and skilled guys (even if of course I don't know if they have time to help you). Here the ways to contact them: https://www.getmonero.org/community/workgroups/

Comment: thanks you!!!!!